# Select a custom entry in a dropdown with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am trying to select an element from a dropdown in Python with Selenium. It consists on different values from 1 to 11. Users are supposed to click the dropdown, click on the value from 1 to 11, and the corresponding research page appears. Here is the HTML code of the dropdown :

```
<select id="page" name="page" class="form-control-sm form-control"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option></select>
```

So the element has ID "page" and consists in a dropdown with different values (option) from 1 to 11.
When I use chrome and go to "inspect element", I can edit the value in quotation marks, for example change "2" and put "30" instead, and when I click on the second dropdown option, it gets me page 30. So it's adaptative. I would like to do it in Selenium in an algorithm.
I was able to select the dropdown menu using :

```
b = driver.find_element_by_id("page")
```

But how could we do with Selenium to select in the dropdown a custom value ? Or edit one of the dropdown options to change the value from "2" to "30" for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the attribute value like this :

```
element =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("option[value = '2']");
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '30')", element);
```

Now that drop down will have `30` instead of `2`.

you can select it by running the below code :-

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('page'))
select.select_by_value('30')
```

should help you get land on 30th page.

Comment: @user16664698 : No issue my friend. Did it work for you  ?